# Flash exports to MOV but cannot import the same file

Tags: flash, video, actionscript

I would like to play external video files from Flash template in Caspar using FLV Playback component, but they need to be high quality and with alpha channel. Flash only allows me to export animations as .mov, but that format is not supported by Flash when you want to import or play it (which I find absurd). I tried converting to .flv and it works, but without alpha and it is low quality. Which formats should I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

you need a flv video with the On2VP6 codec (with alpha channel)
It's the only video format that can read flash with an alpha channel.

One example of software to convert a .mov to On2VP6 is Adobe Media Encoder CC (version 7.0.0.374). 
This is a old version watch. The On2VP6 export is no longer supported in newer versions such as Adobe Media Encoder CC 2014.

To install an older version of Adobe Media Coder, it's not very logical !
you need to use the 'Creative Cloud' application, click the 'After Effects' drop-down list and choose 'CC', it will also install Media Encoder CC.
More information here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1597812

Or install old version of Premiere Pro CC, After Effects CC, Flash CC or InDesign CC : https://forums.adobe.com/message/6527972#6527972

You can also play the video by Caspar on a layer and play the template on another layer. And call them at the same time by your client

Comment: **FFmpeg** is another software that can convert video file formats (including On2VP6). It can run standalone or be found in software like **Super** or **Format Factory** etc... Also ON2 now owned by Google so maybe it's removed cos of license / permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I converted to flv with alpha using an older version of Adobe Media Encoder.

Comment: Solved now? Please mark @molecule's Answer as correct ( click the `✔` icon).